# Is there a way to schedule imports to Firebase within the dashboard?

Tags: json, firebase

I have an external URL that returns JSON data, is there anyway within Firebase to schedule my database to import the data at the URL?

I'd like to schedule the import daily however I can't find any tutorials to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The dashboard isn't the right way to do this.  If you want to put data into Realtime Database on a schedule, use an external scheduling system, such as the [cron system found in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron), to trigger some code that you write that adds the data you want.  You can use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to write that code or simply use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) to put JSON into the place you want.